# C++ Can Inherited Methods Use Child Class Members

Tags: c++, inheritance

As the title states, in C++ can inherited methods use child class members?

For example suppose we define a solid to have a property (a volume) and a method that returns the property. Then in the child class, say a box, we have the same property. Will the inherited method return the parent class's property or the child class's property?

And as an extension to that, can inherited methods use child class specific (overridden) implementations of methods also defined in the parent class? Or would the best solution be to pass in function pointers?

EDIT:

For the extension part of the question consider this example:

```cpp
class A{
   public: 
        void foo(){ 
           foo2(); 
        } 
        void foo2(){ 
           // implementation here 
        }
}

class B:A{ 
   public: 
        void foo2(){ 
           // child implementation here 
        } 
}

int main(){ 
  B b; 
  A a; 
  b.foo(); // I want foo to use b's implementation of foo2
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with virtual functions? Then you get something like `virtual volume_t getVolume() const { return {}; }` in the base class, and `volume_t getVolume() const override { return m_width * m_height * m_depth; }` in the derived class.

Comment: Not really, I'm mostly just familiar with C and Java. Still really just learning C++

Comment: It seems that virtual functions wouldn't be quite appropriate here since I want the inherited  method (say method A) to contain calls to overridden methods defined in the child class, i.e., method A contains calls to methods B, C that are both defined in the parent and child, but I want method A (which is not overridden in the child) to use the child class implementations of B,C

Comment: I think I know what you want, but showing it in code form would help make sure that we're actually thinking the same thing. So I suggest writing realistic code for a parent and child class, and then add in the parts that you want to make work (at least as comments if nothing else). Then someone should be able to give a clear answer on how to achieve it.

Comment: Done! Added the edit

Comment: If you declare `foo2` to be virtual, you'll get the dynamic-dispatch behavior that you want (i.e. `A::foo()` will call `B::foo2()` when appropriate)

Comment: Oh interesting. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: I should declare ```B::foo2()``` to be virtual right?

Answer (score 0):

It is able to be realized using [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which utilize template.

```
template<class Derived>
class A {
public:
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo2();
    }
};

class B :public A<B> {
public:
    void foo2() {
        // child implementation here 
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo(); // Uses foo to use b's implementation of foo2
}
```